# Not able to generate java wrapper class from solidity smart contract using truffle

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, etherscan, web3j, java

I'm trying to generate java wrapper class of solidity smart contract using truffle but not getting wrapperclass.java file
[image]

Here is an command which i've used to generate abi/Json of that contract

```
anikett@anikett:~/myproject$ ls -l build/contracts/
```

total 104
-rw-r--r-- 1 anikett anikett 53703 Oct 16 12:12 Migrations.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 anikett anikett 45796 Oct 16 12:12 Wallet.json

after that used this command which im using for geration of java wrapper class

```
anikett@anikett:~/myproject$ truffle generate ./build/contracts/Wallot.json -o . -p /home/anikett/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.9.RELEASE/JavaEthereumConnectionExample/src/main/java/com/ethereum/connect.javaethereum.wrapper
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing same error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to generate a Java smart contract wrapper you should use the web3j cli. You can still use truffles contract schema.

`$ web3j truffle generate [--javaTypes|--solidityTypes] /path/to/<truffle-smart-contract-output>.json -o /path/to/src/main/java -p com.your.organisation.name`

https://web3j.readthedocs.io/en/latest/smart_contracts.html

Comment: I tried but getting the same error. Unknown options: '--solidtyTypes', './build/contracts/SimpleStorage.json', '-o', '.', '-p', 'java

Comment: web3j truffle generate --solidtyTypes ./build/contracts/SimpleStorage.json -o . -p java